# How to retrieve value from a table in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, nlp, text-classification

This is a HTML page that generates an Arabic poem.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td><pre>{{poemm}}</pre></td>
        <td><pre>{{poem}}</pre></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to retrieve the generated poem from the table and use it in the prediction process but I didn't know-how. I searched and found out that I need to use the request form but I didn't know-how in a table.

This is my code for the prediction process:

```
    elif request.form['action'] == 'Classify':
        train = pd.read_excel('/home/sirina/Desktop/Project/Corpus2/Two-versed Poems/corpusTwoColumnsTrain.xlsx')
        Quasida = [' '.join([x,y]) for x,y in zip(train.Sader, train.Ajez)]
        count_vect = CountVectorizer()
        X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(Quasida)
        tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
        X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
        clf = LinearSVC().fit(X_train_tfidf, train.Era)
        #here i need the poem that i generated to predicted
        predicted=clf.predict(count_vect.transform(poem))
        return render_template('testt.html',poem=poem,prediction=predicted[0])
 return render_template('testt.html')
```

PS: I need to retrieve both poem and poemm from the table.

Comment: The poem is generated in the browser\html page?  Does the user type in the poem?

Comment: @Mike67 Nope it generated from an excel file. It's not an input poem